# Spark: list or listbuffer

Tags: scala, apache-spark

New to spark and scala. I’ve heard that where possible I should avoid the list routine as it takes all data back to the driver program which causes delays and is inefficient. I was advised to use listbuffer instead. My objective is to act on data in an rdd but limit movement of data back to driver. Would like some experienced opinion on list or listbuffer and the difference.

Comment: please share an example problem, your question is too vague as of now.

Comment: Generally, we like a minimal, complete, verifiable example of what you are doing. With no code or context, it's difficult to have an idea of what you're trying to do. More info over at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve